# Manage JBoss Stdout Log as we Manage for Application Server Log

Tags: jboss

The App server startup script, where I am writing the log to `"$INST_NAME-stdout.log"` where `INST_NAME=merch
nohup sh $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run_$INST_NAME.sh -b $IPADDRESS -c $INST_NAME > $JBOSS_HOME/server/$INST_NAME/log/$INST_NAME-stdout.log &`

I am using JBoss Version 5 Running on Linux.

The `jboss-log4j.xml`, has the following entry, where the application logs is written to `$INST_NAME-server.log` where `INST_NAME=merch`.

In the above code I have controlled `merch-server.log` by updating the `jboss-log4j.xml` stating the max size of a file should be 500 MB and maximum backup files to be retained is 100.

So when I start my JBoss App server, there are two log files generated as `merch-stdout.log` and `merch-server.log`.

How can I controll/manage the same for the stdout log?

I would require minimum logging into the `merch-stdout.log`. How do I achive this?

I would not prefer to write any archive script or pass the out to `>dev/null`, I would like to know if we can achive this as we have achived for `merch-server.log`.

Comment: <appender name="FILE"    class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
 <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
 <param name="File" value="$JBOSS_HOME/logs/$INST_NAME/$INST_NAME-server.log"/>
 <param name="Append" value="true"/>
 <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500MB"/>
 <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100"/>

 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] [%t] %m%n"/>
 </layout>
</appender>